# How can i reduce cyclomatic complexity from a model

Tags: java, design-patterns, getter-setter

i need to reduce cyclomatic complexity of this model because it has 26, this is a normal class for setters and getters

```
public class DetailRecord {

    private int lengthReference1;
    private int lengthReference2;
    private int lengthPayersNit;
    private int lengthTransactionAmount;
    private String recordType;
    private String payersNit;
    private String payersName;
    private String payersAccountBank;
    private String accountNumberToBeDebited;
    private String transactionType;
    private String transactionAmount;
    private String referenceOne;
    private String referenceTwo;
    private String expirationDateOrApplicationDate;
    private String billedPeriods;
    private String cycle;
    private String reserved;
    private String validationNit;
    private String encabezadoTotal;

    public DetailRecord() {
        lengthReference1 = 30;
        lengthReference2 = 30;
        lengthPayersNit = 13;
        lengthTransactionAmount = 17;
        recordType = "6";
        payersName = "                    ";
    }

    public int getLengthReference1() {
        return lengthReference1;
    }

    public int getLengthReference2() {
        return lengthReference2;
    }

    public int getLengthPayersNit() {
        return lengthPayersNit;
    }

    public int getLengthTransactionAmount() {
        return lengthTransactionAmount;
    }

    public String getRecordType() {
        return recordType;
    }

    public String getPayersName() {
        return payersName;
    }

    public String getPayersAccountBank() {
        return payersAccountBank;
    }
}
```

How can i reduce the cyclomatic complexity? Using a builder perhaps or what else can I do? Abstract the class or maybe create a interface?

Comment: How using getters/setters count towards cyclomatic complexity?

Comment: it counts each return

Comment: As user7 said, Cyclomatic complexity mainly depends on branching conditions. I your case it is just a Bean, so I dont think this would count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have reduce the ciclomatyc complexity using factory method,

```
public class DetailRecord extends StringManager {
private final String RECORD_TYPE = "06";
private String userMainReference;
private String secondaryReferenceOfTheUser;
private static final String BILLER_PERIODS = "00";
private String cycle;
private String mainServiceValue;
private static final String BILLED_SERVICE_CODE_BY_ADDITIONAL_COMPANY = "             ";
private static final String ADDITIONAL_SERVICE_VALUE = "              ";
private String expirationDate;
private String collectingBankId;
private String targetAccountNumber;
private String billerAccountType;
private String noBillerId;
private String billerName;
private static final String SOURCE_BANK_CODE = "   ";
private static final String RESERVED = "                        ";
private static final int lengthOfUserMainReference = 48;
private static final int lengthOfTheSecondaryReferenceOfTheUser = 30;
private static final int lengthOfTheCycle = 3;
private static final int lengthOfTheMainServiceValue = 14;
private static final int lengthOfTheCollectingBankId = 8;
private static final int lengthOfTargetAccountNumber = 17;
private static final int lengthOfNoBillerId = 10;
private static final int lengthOfBillerName = 22;


public DetailRecord(String userMainReference, String secondaryReferenceOfTheUser, String cycle, String mainServiceValue, String expirationDate, String collectingBankId, String targetAccountNumber, String billerAccountType, String noBillerId, String billerName) {
    this.userMainReference = userMainReference;
    this.secondaryReferenceOfTheUser = secondaryReferenceOfTheUser;
    this.cycle = cycle;
    this.mainServiceValue = mainServiceValue;
    this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
    this.collectingBankId = collectingBankId;
    this.targetAccountNumber = targetAccountNumber;
    this.billerAccountType = billerAccountType;
    this.noBillerId = noBillerId;
    this.billerName = billerName;
}

public static DetailRecord createWith(String userMainReference, String secondaryReferenceOfTheUser, String cycle, String mainServiceValue, String expirationDate, String collectingBankId, String targetAccountNumber, String billerAccountType, String noBillerId, String billerName) {
    return new DetailRecord(userMainReference, secondaryReferenceOfTheUser, cycle, mainServiceValue, expirationDate, collectingBankId, targetAccountNumber, billerAccountType, noBillerId, billerName);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return new StringBuilder()
            .append(RECORD_TYPE)
            .append(fillInWithZerosLeftPad(userMainReference, lengthOfUserMainReference))
            .append(fillInWithBlanksLeftPad(secondaryReferenceOfTheUser, lengthOfTheSecondaryReferenceOfTheUser))
            .append(BILLER_PERIODS)
            .append(fillInWithBlanksLeftPad(cycle, lengthOfTheCycle))
            .append(fillInWithZerosLeftPad(mainServiceValue, lengthOfTheMainServiceValue))
            .append(BILLED_SERVICE_CODE_BY_ADDITIONAL_COMPANY)
            .append(ADDITIONAL_SERVICE_VALUE)
            .append(expirationDate)
            .append(fillInWithZerosLeftPad(collectingBankId, lengthOfTheCollectingBankId))
            .append(fillInWithBlanksLeftPad(targetAccountNumber, lengthOfTargetAccountNumber))
            .append(billerAccountType)
            .append(fillInWithBlanksLeftPad(noBillerId, lengthOfNoBillerId))
            .append(fillInWithBlanksLeftPad(billerName, lengthOfBillerName))
            .append(SOURCE_BANK_CODE)
            .append(RESERVED).toString();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could use composition, breaking this class into multiple classes and decouple unrelated things. That way, you would have multiple classes, making it easier to maintain and scale, as well as reduce the cyclomatic complexity.